# Dogged persistence of NetworkManager

Tags: network-manager

18.04 MATE

I have apt purged NetworkManager and deleted any residual NM files I find, yet there re-appears a NetworkManager directory in /run.

And most curious there is this :

```
root@home:/etc/netplan# netplan --debug generate
DEBUG:command generate: running ['/lib/netplan/generate']
   ...
** (generate:4435): DEBUG: 17:11:44.918: NetworkManager: definition enp0s3 is not for us (backend 1)
```

Why is is this? How can I be rid of NM?

**This just in**: *These  two NM vestiges exist in a new installation of Ubuntu server 18.04. 
This is very strange.*

@chili555 At Chili's request, here is my netplan yaml:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      addresses: [192.168.0.121/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        search: [michigan]
        addresses: [192.168.0.110]
```

Comment: Please edit your question to post your current yaml file.

Comment: @chili555 Done.